# How to disable adaptive sampling while passing instrumentationKey in AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()

Tags: azure-application-insights, appinsights

Currently what I did in startup class is:

```
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(<MyAppInsightsInstrumentationKey>);
```

According to official example, to disable adaptive sampling we should pass the ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions to services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(): [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#use-applicationinsightsserviceoptions)

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService;

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
    // Disables adaptive sampling.
    aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;

    // Disables QuickPulse (Live Metrics stream).
    aiOptions.EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false;
    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(aiOptions);
}
```

Since I am already passing the instrumentationKey. What's the proper way to disable adaptive sampling in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer:

```
var aiOptions = new ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions
{
    // Disables adaptive sampling.
    EnableAdaptiveSampling = false,
    // Disables QuickPulse (Live Metrics stream).
    EnableQuickPulseMetricStream = false,
    InstrumentationKey = <MyInstrumentationKey>
};
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(aiOptions);
```